# Forwarding unknown arguments and options to commands using Context.forward

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I try to build a command line application that has several single commands with different options, but also a general command which should execute every single command as well.

The code looks currently like this:

```py
import click


@click.group()
def cli():
    ...


@cli.command('mod1', context_settings=dict(ignore_unknown_options=True, allow_extra_args=True))
@click.argument('arg1')
@click.argument('arg2')
@click.option('--option1')
@click.pass_context
def mod1(ctx, arg1, arg2, option1):
    print('Running mod1')
    print(ctx.params)
    print(ctx.args)


@cli.command('mod2', context_settings=dict(ignore_unknown_options=True, allow_extra_args=True))
@click.argument('arg1')
@click.argument('arg2')
@click.option('--option1')
@click.option('--option2')
@click.pass_context
def mod2(ctx, arg1, arg2, option1, option2):
    print('Running mod2')
    print(ctx.params)


@cli.command('mod3', context_settings=dict(ignore_unknown_options=True, allow_extra_args=True))
@click.argument('arg1')
@click.pass_context
def mod3(ctx, arg1):
    print('Running mod3')
    print(ctx.params)


function_mapping = {
    'mod1': mod1,
    'mod2': mod2,
    'mod3': mod3,
}


@cli.command('all', context_settings=dict(ignore_unknown_options=True, allow_extra_args=True))
@click.argument('arg1')
@click.argument('arg2')
@click.option('--option1')
@click.option('--option2')
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx, arg1, arg2, option1, option2):
    print('Running all commands')
    print(ctx.params)
    print(ctx.args)
    for mod in function_mapping:
        ctx.forward(function_mapping[mod])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

The problem is, that whenever `mod1` is executed, the script fails with the error message `TypeError: mod1() got an unexpected keyword argument 'option2'`. According to [this link](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/advanced/#forwarding-unknown-options), paragraph 1, this should work and extra arguments are captured to `ctx.args`.

Click version used here is 8.0.4, Python 3.8.10.

Any ideas or hints on this? Many thinks in advance.

**EDIT**
Is has something to do with `ctx.forward`. If I specify `mod1` as command and add any other option, it works and those unknown options are seen in `ctx.args`.